# How to satisfy the warnings about incompatible types on printf()

Tags: c, types, casting

I am going through the tutorials on learn-c.org. Coming up to the section about [Arrays and Pointers](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Arrays_and_Pointers), the first two lines of the example program issue a warning if I run them on my system:

```c
char vowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
char *pvowels = &vowels;
```

The code runs, but I get the following warning:

> warning: initialization of ‘char *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char (*)[5]’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>      15 |  char *pvowels = &vowels;

I can get rid of this warning if i cast it as

```c
char *pvowels = (char *) &vowels;
```

But is that the correct way to approach that warning, just to cast it? It seems unnecessary in the first place, i don't really understand the difference between `char *` and `char (*)`.

---

Next, the `printf` line issues a warning for the 3rd argument, saying:

> warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]

(same for arguments 5 and 7)

This one i don't even know how to cast in order to bypass the warning... What would be the correct way to print this one?

---

#### Entire program from their tutorial for reference:

```c
char vowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
char *pvowels = &vowels;
int i;

// Print the addresses
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("&vowels[%d]: %u, pvowels + %d: %u, vowels + %d: %u\n", i, &vowels[i], i, pvowels + i, i, vowels + i);
}

// Print the values
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("vowels[%d]: %c, *(pvowels + %d): %c, *(vowels + %d): %c\n", i, vowels[i], i, *(pvowels + i), i, *(vowels + i));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `&vowels` you get a pointer to the array itself, which is of type `char (*)[5]` as mentioned in the error message. What you seem to want is a pointer to the *first element* in the array which would be `&vowels[0]`, or plain `vowels` as that *decays* to a pointer to its first element:

```
char *pvowels = vowels;
```

---

Also, when you want to print pointers with [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you need to use the `%p` format. And it prints "generic" pointers of type `void *`, so to be fully correct you need to cast all pointers to `void *`

```
printf("&vowels[%d]: %p, pvowels + %d: %p, vowels + %d: %p\n", i, (void *) &vowels[i], i, (void *) (pvowels + i), i, (void *) (vowels + i));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char vowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
char *pvowels = &vowels;
```

Here `vowels` is an array and if you take the address, you get the address of an array.
`pvowels` is of type pointer to `char`, not `pointer to array`.

If you want to get the address of the first character, just use the name of the array. It will decay to pointer to first element which is what you need:

```
char *pvowels = vowels;
```

---

Your second message comes because you use wrong types:

```
// Print the addresses
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("&vowels[%d]: %u, pvowels + %d: %u, vowels + %d: %u\n", i, &vowels[i], i, pvowels + i, i, vowels + i);
}
```

You want to print an address. The message is very clear that `%u` is used to print integers, not addresses. Use `%p` instead and provide parameter of type `void*`:

types:

```
// Print the addresses
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("&vowels[%d]: %p, pvowels + %d: %p, vowels + %d: %p\n", i, (void*)&vowels[i], i, (void*)(pvowels + i), i, (void*)(vowels + i));
}
```